# SDL_Window does not display after build/compilation, Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: c, eclipse, sdl, sdl-2, ubuntu-20.04

Currently using SDL2, and attempting to output a basic SDL Window (Ubuntu 20.04) with the C programming language. Program runs, window does not display.

Would like to preface that I've gotten the SDL_Window to show up once before, but **(possibly unrelated)** after the successful integration of SDL2_gfx, there seems to be issues with the window displaying.

I've run the code both on the Eclipse IDE and in the main linux command line, same error persists, with both a clean build, and a successful compilation, but the window does not show on the screen.

See code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

      SDL_Window *window;

      if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0){
            printf("SDL could not initialize! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
            return 1;
            }

      window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL Example", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 800, 600, SDL_WINDOW_ALLOW_HIGHDPI);

      if(window == NULL){
            printf("SDL window failed to initialize: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
            return 1;
      }

      SDL_Event e;
      int quit = 0;
      while(quit == 0){
            while(SDL_PollEvent(&e)){
                  if(e.type == SDL_QUIT){
                        quit = 1;
                  }
                  if(e.type == SDL_KEYDOWN){
                        quit = 1;
                  }
                  if(e.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN){
                        quit = 1;
                  }
            }
       }

       SDL_DestroyWindow(window);

       SDL_Quit();

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Few points/disclaimers: This question has been asked by MacOS users, some suggestions include putting in

if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0)...
vs

if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)....
This has been attempted but I do not have audio support configured for SDL

Also....

SDL_WINDOW_ALLOW_HIGHDPI
Has been changed to various flags, and this has been unsuccessful.

Any advice/suggestions/solutions?

Comment: FYI I tried your code (on Ubuntu 22.04) and it works. The window appears.

Comment: Could you elaborate about SDL_gfx? Do you link with it in this example program? Consider adding `RenderClear`/`RenderPresent`.

Comment: Are you running this under X11?  Wayland?  Console?  Are you using Ubuntu's SDL package or a self-built one?

Comment: If you're running under Wayland you might need to add the RenderClear/RenderPresent in the main loop for the window to show. I believe that when you're using the Wayland back-end it is a requirement that you draw something in the window for it to appear

Comment: This is Ubuntu's SDL package, RenderClear/RenderPresent and drawing to the background then pushing to the foreground window has been tried, still no avail. @pmacfarlane good to know it works as well, will create another Ubuntu instance in VirtualBox, and reattempt.

Comment: Circling back, this issue has been resolved. The reason being, the SDL_gfx package was not installed within the properly SDL2 file path, this led fatal inconsistencies in all paths, meaning SDL2 could not longer be properly accessed with all dependencies by a linux machine. Solution was to delete entire linux image, and create a new. I highly recommend referencing this public github tutorial on how to download SDL2 and any SDL2 dependencies. subhttps://gist.github.com/aaangeletakis/3187339a99f7786c25075d4d9c80fad5